# Oracle APEX 20 -select list error Buffer to Small Ask Question

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex 20, I created a select list  to  retrieve data  from a view which has a column return  a polygon(clob column) (map latitude longitude)
look like the picture
[returned value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83eKD.png)
. If I reduce the returned value it's working file but i don't need that

list error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

I guess the question is: How to increase buffer to run this select list?
note :- it's working fine in apex 18

Comment: Are you saying that that massive JSON object is the return value of an option in the select list?  That would be crazy...

Comment: yes. i think that crazy ,the application already was built with this structure , i am only fix bugs and add some enhancement to this application

Comment: Yes, I think the functionality should be redesigned to use APEX properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the user to select one from a number of possible polygon JSON objects, then you should assign each polygon some sort of key value - e.g. a number, or a code.  Your select list should return the number or code, not the whole polygon JSON object.

Once they have selected the code, **then** you can use it to look up and retrieve the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "polygon data" means. What is it?

Anyway: as far as I understood the problem, a workaround is to switch to a **Pop up** list of values (instead of a Select List)

Comment: sorry polygon it's mean (map latitude longitude) ,   i will that thank's

Comment: i tried that but not working , i have modified the question you can see the returned value in picture (clob), it's working fine in apex 18 but in apex 19 and 20 this error appear

Comment: I see ... What do you do with such a return value? Could you rewrite it and return e.g. polygon's **ID** (or something), and then use that ID in future calculations (or whatever you're doing with it)? Because, looking at what is being returned, it is useless for human usage.

Comment: the application work with ARCGIS map ,I'm using the value to reprint the map

Comment: OK, but - as I said (as well as Tony in his answer) - you should be selecting some kind of an ID, not the whole polygon in select list (or pop up LoV, doesn't matter).